# Provisioning profiles for Service Extension and Content Extension

Tags: swift, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-app-extension, rich-notifications

I am trying to implement Rich notifications in my iOS application and while using **Notification Service Extension** and **Notification Content Extension**, post running my app I am getting error of same bundle identifier.
For these extensions do I need to use separate provisioning profiles?
Like one for my code, one for Notification Service Extension and one for Notification Content Extension?

Comment: every extension and service requires app bundle id only. provisioning profile is only for installing app and related extension thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have to use separate provisioning profile for **Notification Service Extension and Notification Content Extension**. For reference you can use this link.

> https://mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/mguide/ios-10-rich-notifications-tutorial/

Service extensions:

A Service extension’s entry point class
UNNotificationServiceExtension

It overrides 2 methods:

```
func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
}

func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
}
```

Content extension’s entry point class is
UIViewController and it implements protocol

```
func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks Ravish for the confirmation! will make separate profiles and check out.

Comment: Is there any rule that the profile names of the extensions should match the profile name of apps profile?

Comment: I am getting this error: ->  error: Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier.

Comment: Target->General-->Embedded Binaries delete the older and select the new this was how i solved this problem

Comment: What is the lowest iOS version that supports Rich Notifications?, As if I need to support iOS 9 too, how to handle it?

Comment: iOS 10 rich notifications will come to devices without 3D Touch. You can follow below link.https://mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/mguide/ios-10-rich-notifications-tutorial/

Comment: is these necessary to generate new app id in apple developer account ? like" (app bundle id).Content"

Comment: The bundle identifier of your notification service has to be prefixed like: com.YourCompany.YourApp.NotificationService while your app identifier is com.YourCompany.YourApp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create the separate certificates (dev and release) for  **Notification Service Extension**.

[image]

Also you should include the **mutable-content** key and set **true** in your payload as shown below.

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "test title",
            "body": "test message"
        },
        "mutable-content": 1
    },
    and more...
}
```